# List bpy.types in a scene including empties

Tags: python

In the example shown below, all `bpy.types` are found, except that for the empty. Is it possible to add code to find the `bpy.type` for the empty as well? This is Blender 2.81a.

[image: Blender screenshot]

The code is listed below and the [.blend file can be downloaded here.](http://ge.tt/2WAMgl03)

```
import bpy,os

# Clean the terminal window, on linux/mac use 'clear', on windows use 'cls'
os.system('cls')

for obj in bpy.data.objects:

    print("\nObject name:",obj.name)

    if type(obj.data) == bpy.types.Mesh:
        print("bpy.type: MESH")

    if type(obj.data) == bpy.types.PointLight:
        print("bpy.type: LIGHT")

    if type(obj.data) == bpy.types.Camera:
        print("bpy.type: Camera")

#    How to find the Empty? This code does not work:
#    if type(obj.data) == bpy.types.Empty: 
#        print("Type: Empty")
```

Comment: For an empty object (and only an empty object)  `obj.data is None` will be true.  AFAIK there is no `bpy.types.Empty`  Suggest using the `Object.type` property as answered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I guess, you just want to execute something based on the actual type of object while running through a list of objects in the scene*. In this case, better use the `type` attribute of each object, which returns (as you probably guess) the type per object so no need to compare against `RNA types`:

```
>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Empty']

>>> C.object.type
'EMPTY'
```

Test all objects of the *collection in context* (active collection):

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context

for obj in C.collection.objects:
    # Check for geometry type
    if obj.type not in ('EMPTY', 'CAMERA', 'LIGHT'):
        print ("Geometry object:", obj.name)
    # Check for empty
    elif obj.type == 'EMPTY':
        print ("Empty object:", obj.name)
        # Print the type
        print ("Draw type:", obj.empty_display_type)
```

API: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=type#bpy.types.Object.type

All types of objects for reference: `'MESH', 'CURVE', 'SURFACE', 'META', 'FONT', 'ARMATURE', 'LATTICE', 'EMPTY', 'GPENCIL', 'CAMERA', 'LIGHT', 'SPEAKER', 'LIGHT_PROBE'`

Comment: Is it possible to distinguish between different types of empties, e.g. `Plain Axes` and `Arrows`?

Comment: Sure, answer updated @John You can enable *Developer Extras and Python Tooltips* (*Prefs > Interface*) which allows to display the python property within the UI.